# Running Javascript Functions Sync

Tags: javascript, arrays, closures

I am trying to make a javascript program that can take an array of words and output  each word  letter by letter in the screen and then delete each letter and go with the next word in the array. I have manage to make it work with one word of the array but when I use two or more they mesh with each other as if the were call async or in parallel. This is the code:

```js
const words_js = document.querySelector('.words-js');
const words = [
  'driven',
  'condident',
  'creative',
  'inspired',
  'productive',
  'focused',
  'fullfiling'
];

function runWords() {
  words.forEach((word, index) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      runLetter(word, 2, 0);
    }, 1000 * (index))

  });

}

function runLetter(word, max, count) {
  count = count + 1;
  if (count > max) {
    return
  };
  [...word].forEach((letter, index) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (count === 1) {
        words_js.innerHTML += letter;
      } else {
        words_js.innerHTML = word.substring(0, word.length - index);
      }
      if (index === ([...word].length - 1)) {
        runLetter(word, max, count)
      }
    }, index * 1000);
  });
}
runWords();
```

```html
<span class="words-js"></span>
```

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: Thats exactly what setTimeout() is!!! It is asynchronous in nature.

Comment: If you want to be notified when function is done, pass a function and call it, or use promises

Comment: This is a good case use for `async/await` and [`for await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments all mentioned, using `setTimeout` is making your calls asynchronous. On top of that, you run into the problem of scoping by using `setTimeout` in a loop. This issue can be solved by scoping your setTimeout using [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression).

```
(function (_i) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          /*** some code ***/
          }, _i * delay)
        }(i)
```

Another issue, is that your code has no way of letting you know it's done. So you can't process your queue of words.

This problem can be solved by taking another approach and some language features.

I think ( I may be mistaken ) you're trying to achieve a typed words effect. So I will name my functions accordingly.

`typeWord(word, delay cb)` Takes a word and generates a sequence of the strings: eg word = "abc" => `["a", "ab", "abc", "ab", "a", ""]` and then applies the callback to each item in the array using the giving delay as an interval.

It's wrapped in a Promise, this way you can attach a callback to the `.then()` when the function is resolved.

The `typedWords(words, delay, cb)` is a recursive function that takes an array of words and passes it to the `typeWord` function one by one synchronously. It waits for the current word to finish before continuing.

Lastly you add the callback to actually change your div:  `(s) => words_js.innerHTML = s`

```js
const words_js = document.querySelector('.words-js');
const words = [
  'driven',
  'condident',
  'creative',
  'inspired',
  'productive',
  'focused',
  'fullfiling'
];
     
    function typeWord(word, delay, cb) {
      let rangeOfWordLength = [...Array(word.length * 2)]
      // Create an array of word segments 
      let seq = rangeOfWordLength.map((_, i) => (i >= word.length) ? word.slice(0, -(i + 1 - word.length)) : word.slice(0, i + 1));
      // wrap each segment in a Promise which resolved after callback
      let promises = seq.map((segment, i) => new Promise(_r => {
      // Proper scoping
        (function(_i) {
          setTimeout(() => {
        
            cb(segment, _r);
    
          }, _i * delay)
        }(i))
    
      }));
      
      // Return a promise that only fires after all the previous promises have resolved
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        Promise.all(promises).then(resolve)
      })
    }
    
    async function typedWords(words, delay, cb) {
      if (words.length) {
        let next = words.shift()
        await typeWord(next, delay, cb);
        return typedWords(words, delay, cb);
      }
      return true;
    }
    typedWords(words, 500, (s, next) => { words_js.innerHTML = s; next();})
```

```html
<span class="words-js"></span>
```

Comment: Great implementation! Learn a lot from it.

Comment: In the typeWord function I am trying to figure out how you made it to generate the array as `["a", "ab", "abc", "ab", "a", ""]` if in the map function you return a promise and after when  you use  `Promise.all(seq.map...` the seq var alredy have an array with the `["a", "ab", "abc", "ab", "a", ""]` form eventhough you are just initalizing it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I split the code and added comments. I hope it's clear whichpart generates the seq and which part wraps them with promises.